# Can I create an 'everyone can post' style site with wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

A friend and I came up with an extremely simple idea for a website. Essentially we want people to be able to visit the site and quickly post a piece of text without having to register or sign in etc. Like a blog where everyone can contribute.

I noticed that wordpress allow you to install their software on your own server, do they only offer conventional blogs, or would it be easy to set something like this up?

I could write the server read/write stuff myself, but I have no faith in my ability to design a nice looking site, so just using a template would be best.

Comment: Be prepared to handle/filter a torrent of spam/ads

Comment: well I guess I'll pop a captcha up there too

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to have people sign up but you could set-up the default account as contributor or editor or something like that. Sounds though you might be better using some wiki software instead?